# Order of $x$ with $x^p=a$

Tags: group-theory

Using only elementary group theory.

> Let G be a group with an element $a$ of order $k$. Let $p$ a prime which divides $k$.  If there is $x$ in G with $x^p=a$, show that $x$ has order $pk$.

**My attempt:**

We know that $x$ has finite order, say $m$, because $x^{kp}=1$.  Then $m$ divides $kp$.
If we show that $kp$ divides $m$ we are done. But how?

This question is in Advanced morden algebra, Rotman page 62 before Lagrange Theorem

Comment: What have you tried?  What is $x^{pk}$?

Comment: Thanks, I have added my attempt.

Comment: Does this not follow immediately from the formula
$$\mathrm{ord}(x^n)=\frac{\mathrm{ord}(x)}{\gcd(n,\mathrm{ord}(x))}?$$
Set $n=p$, when we know that the left hand side is equal to $k$. Therefore $p\mid\mathrm{ord}(x)$, and hence the gcd in the denominator is $p$, and we are done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, can you prove that formula?

Comment: That's probably in all the books I've seen. Let $m=\mathrm{ord}(x)$. Then $x^\ell=1$ if and only if $m\mid \ell$. Therefore $(x^n)^i=1$ if and only if $m\mid ni$. Elementary number theory gives that that the smallest positive $i$ for which this holds is $m/\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ divides $k$ so $k=pq$ where $q<k$. Since $x^p=a$ and $a$ has order $k$, so $x^{pk}=e$. Therefore if $m$ is the order of $x$, then $m$ divides $pk$. Suppose $m\neq pk$ so that $m<pk$. We claim that $\gcd(m, p)=1$ because otherwise $m=ps$ for some $s<k$ and so $$a^s=x^{ps}=x^m=e$$ which is a contradiction. So we have $$m|k=pq\Rightarrow m|q\Rightarrow q=mr$$ for some $r$. This gives $$a^q=x^{pq}=x^{pmr}=e$$ which is a contradiction because $a$ has order $k$ and $q<k$. Hence $m=pk$.

Comment: Why if $m$ does not divide $p$ then $m$ divides $q$?

Comment: @asv Because $m$ divides $p^2q$.

Comment: but if m=15 and p=3 and q=5 we have m divides  $p^2q$, m doesn't divide p but also m does not divide q

Comment: You are right. I need to add that $gcd(m, p)=1$. I will do that shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^p=a$ and $a$ has order $k$, we have the $k$ elements $1,x^p,x^{2p},\dots,x^{(k-1)p}$ are all distinct, and forms a subgroup of the subgroup generated by $x$.  Hence the order of $x$ must be a multiple of $k$.

So to show $x$ has order $kp$, it suffices to show $x^k\neq e$.

Since $p$ divides $k$, we have $k=p\ell$, $\ell$ is a positive integer $<k$ and thus $x^k=(x^p)^\ell=a^\ell\neq e$.  QED.

Comment: Why to show x has order $kp$, it suffices to show $x^k$≠e?

Comment: Because the order of $x$ must be a multiple of $k$, and the only multiples of $k$ that are divisors of $kp$ are $k$ and $kp$.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to solve it without using Lagrange Theoem? This question is in Advanced morden algebra, Rotman page 62 before Lagrange Theorem